# CSS Changing Logo Hover Color

Tags: css, colors, hover

I've managed to change the Logo the way I want it using Logo using CSS but I'm struggling to figure out how to change the hover color of it.

I want to change the TEST color on hover from blue to something else
http://test.peterstavrou.com/

At the moment my CSS code is

```
header#top #logo {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 35px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your Logo-Text is a link so you should use css-syntax for styling links:

```
a#logo:link { color: #fff; } /* a Link that has not been clicked yet */
a#logo:visited { color: #fff; } /* a link that has been clicked before */
a#logo:hover { color: #ff0; } /* a link on hover/rollover */
a#logo:active { color: #ff0; } /* a link that is just clicked */
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like:

**Solutions 1** Find the logo hover css and change the color property value to whatever color you want

```
color: red!important; /* change the property value to the color you want */
```

**Solution 2**  Create another hover CSS and force a change as shown below, if the above doesn't work

```
#logo:hover {
    color: red!important;
    }
```

**Note:**  Make sure the code above is at the very bottom of your css file. that way, it will override the previous hover property defined, even if it has important

Answer (score 0):

Add this below the code for `header#top #logo { ... }` that your sample is showing in the CSS.

```
header#top #logo:hover
{
color:red;
}
```